# How to emit code that calls a dynamic method?

Tags: c#, reflection, reflection.emit, ilgenerator

I'm trying to emit code that calls a dynamic method that I emitted earlier:

```
iLGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, dynamicMethod.GetMethodInfo());
```

It troughs an exception saying: **"MethodInfo must be a runtime MethodInfo object"**

Is there a way to convert a *dynamic* method into a *runtime* method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell you've already compiled the `DynamicMethod` into a delegate using `CreateDelegate`. However, if you just use the `DynamicMethod` object directly as the parameter to Emit it should work. A demonstration:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod("test1", typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);
        var gen = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
        gen.EmitWriteLine("Test");
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var dynMethod2 = new DynamicMethod("test2", typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);
        gen = dynMethod2.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, dynMethod);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var method2 = (Action)dynMethod2.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action));
        method2();
    }
}
```